# Trigger inotify file change event

Tags: c, linux, inotify

How can I trigger linux inotify() file change event programmatically, without real read/write operation?

Inotify [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) has only watching functions.

Actually I have to do it without any file operation.
Maybe there is a possibility to do this via some system call ?

Comment: `sed '' -i filename` without real change so inotify will trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can change attributes to trigger an event for inotify() to report.  You might change permissions, for example.

I used udev rules to write to a file upon thumb drive insertion, then inotify() to detect that write, and kicked off scripts to process everything on the drive, all without user interaction.  inotify() is a very useful call.

Comment: Actually I have to do it without any file operation.
Maybe there is a possibility to do this via some system call ?

Comment: @Ruslan: Which flag would you expect to see when successfully reading an event?  Also, what is your end goal?

Comment: I want emulate IN_MODIFY event, without real modifying

Comment: Without a file, you want a notification when what is modified?